# Q: ViewPager and OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

OnClickListener not working use with ViewPager. Without ViewPager working. I'm opening program. And program is running. but when I touch button, button is not working.

Where can write OnClickListener? 
İf I write OnClickListener in PageOne.java I'm getting errors. Because PageOne Class is extends Fragment. Fragment not accepting OnClickListener.
İf I Create new class in PageOne and use "extends activity" not getting errors but button not working.

Here is Page1:

```
package my.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class PageOne extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState) {

        if (container==null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pageone, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here is PageAdapter

```
package my.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 19.02.2015.
 */
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentActivity

    {

        ViewPager viewPager = null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle enes){
        super.onCreate(enes);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }
    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public Fragment getItem (int i) {
            Fragment fragment=null;
            if(i==0)
            {
                fragment=new SSoruBir();
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                fragment=new SoruIki();
            }
            if(i==2)
            {
                fragment=new SoruUc();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        String aa = "SORU 1";


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = new String();
            if (position == 0) {
                return aa;
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                return "SORU 2";
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                return "SORU 3";
            }
            return null;
        }

}
```

** NEW UPDATE**

```
SSoruBir.java
package benim.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class SSoruBir  extends Fragment  {

    View rootView;

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable  Bundle SavedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, SavedInstanceState);
        if (rootView != null)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
            {
                parent.removeView(rootView);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sorubir, container, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Button a;

            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.a);
                a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        a.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        if (container==null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sorubir, container, false);
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sorubir, container, false);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to define onClickListener for each page of your viewPager ?

Comment: Yes right. I want this.

Comment: Set the onClickListener for the rootView of each fragment , Or define the listener in the Adapter and pass it to fragments , Then in the fragment set the listener to rootView.

Comment: I'm a beginner. What is rootView? where codes of rootView? Can u give me some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions that could be used is to define onClickListener in the RootView of your fragment.

You have some fragments such as **SSoruBir** So in the fragment you have a method named `onCreateView` like the following code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if(rootView != null)
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.removeView(rootView);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        // Creating view
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ssorubir, container, false);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    // Here befor returning the view set your onClickListener
    rootView.setOnClickListener(yourOnClickListener);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: AndroidStudio is not accepting "rootView". code color is red. "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: İn my First page I have a button. this button is not working.

Comment: Declare rootView on your fragment class : `View rootView`

Comment: Okey I write this (View rootView) errors are went. But Still I'cant run my button?

Comment: Instead of `rootView.setOnClickListener` try `rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener...`

Comment: I'M updated question write new SSoruBir.java Page is not opening. but not errors. still blank page.

Comment: You should return `rootView` instead of `(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sorubir, container, false);`

Comment: still the same. blank page.